# Has anyone faced this error -- Out of memory (Needed 48984 bytes)?

Tags: mysql, c

Has anyone faced this error: Out of memory (Needed 48984 bytes) before?

Here are the details:

I have a DLL file that contains some mathematical algorithms implemented. These algorithms need around 10k values for their calculation. So we have stored 10k values ina MYSQL database. The DLL uses MYSQL C APIs to import the 10k values and does calculations. It works fine but if I keep the DLL running continuously I get following error -- Out of memory (Needed 48984 bytes).

I hope this explanation would help you to understand issue.  I cannot share the code as I have only DDL file.

Comment: Did you change anything else than the title from your previous question that was closed?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Out of memory (Needed 48984 bytes)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7564156/out-of-memory-needed-48984-bytes)

Comment: Yes i did. I have put the question once again with more information as per requested

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you have a monumental memory leak.  Maybe there is a method in the DLL that you should be using to release the 10k values read from the MySQL database?

Comment: Thanks Jonathan. I observed that i was not using mysql_free_result() [which Frees the memory allocated for a result set by mysql_store_result()] at right place. It is working fine now but i will keep the DLL running for next couple of days. Let see whether the issue is resolved or not.

Answer (score 0):

[SOLVED]:

max_allowed_packet  when dump the DB, must be smaller when restore the DB

example
max_allowed_packet = 16M #when dump DB
max_allowed_packet = 32M #when restore DB